# copy paste resulting into broken indentation in mac visual studio code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I tried copying a **section of code from cloudscape**: https://cloudscape.design/components/table which looks similar to the following image:

[image]

and paste in the visual-studio code,

however this is resulting into the following when done a copy and paste:

```
{          id: "variable",          header: "Variable name",          cell: item => <Link href="#">{item.name}</Link>,          sortingField: "name",          isRowHeader: true        },        {          id: "value",          header: "Text value",          cell: item => item.alt,          sortingField: "alt"        },        {          id: "type",          header: "Type",          cell: item => item.type        },        {          id: "description",          header: "Description",          cell: item => item.description        }
```

Here, our entire code is getting broken with indentation.

Any suggestions how to fix the formatting while copy+paste in mac visual studio code.

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an  image.

Comment: @toyotaSupra the code in text is available here: https://cloudscape.design/components/table

The moment we copy and paste it looses the indentation.